# Gradually increase space between columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, frontend

I am a beginner in the frontend world. I have a panel with columns inside.
However, the data is misaligned from the titles. I believe that I need to increase the padding gradually to align the data with the titles, but I don't know how to do it right.

The system is using bootstrap-3...

Photo:
[image]
The data in the last columns are before the titles and they are gradually misaligned!

The code:

```html
<div id="detail-{{ id }}" class="panel-default quotation-tracking-area header clear-both clearfix">

    <div class="panel-heading tracking-header hidden-xs hidden-sm">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'so' defaultValue="SO #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'invoice' defaultValue="Invoice #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'invoice-date' defaultValue="Invoice Date" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'nf' defaultValue="NF #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>{{ i18n 'payment-status' defaultValue="Payment Status" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'epayments-id' defaultValue="ePayments ID #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>{{ i18n 'payment-date' defaultValue="Payment Date" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'clearing' defaultValue="Clearing #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'view' defaultValue="View" }}</label>
            </div>


        <!-- row -->
        </div>

    <!-- panel-heading -->
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'so' defaultValue="SO #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ salesOrderNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'invoice' defaultValue="Invoice #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ invoiceNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'invoice-date' defaultValue="Invoice Date" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ moment invoiceDate format="MMM/DD/YYYY" }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'nf' defaultValue="NF #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ nf }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'payment-status' defaultValue="Payment Status" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ paymentStatus }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'epayments-id' defaultValue="ePayments ID #" }}:</span>
                <p>Teste</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'payment-date' defaultValue="Payment Date" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ moment paymentDate format="MMM/DD/YYYY" }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'clearing' defaultValue="Clearing #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ clearingDocumentNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs pl-md-3 p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'view' defaultValue="View" }}:</span> 
                <i class="material-icons" color="red">picture_as_pdf</i>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

can someone give me a hint how can i solve it? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: A table would be much easier to format. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/

Comment: ^ yeh: The rows are rendered seperately from eachother, so if one of those strings is too long for it's container, and seeing as it's widths are relative, it'll expand "out of sync" with the other cells. Tables would solve it, or going from row > column, to column > row (but then you'll have the same issue with the height)

Comment: Yes... i know, but the responsive layout will break... I'v reached using css classes, I will post the answer... thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved using a class to set paddings of child divs and removing the div with row class:

```css
.quotation-tracking-item-area div {
  padding: 15px 0 5p
}
```

```html
<div id="detail-{{ id }}" class="panel-default quotation-tracking-area header clear-both clearfix">

    <div class="panel-heading tracking-header hidden-xs hidden-sm">

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'so' defaultValue="SO #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'invoice' defaultValue="Invoice #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'invoice-date' defaultValue="Invoice Date" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'nf' defaultValue="NF #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>{{ i18n 'payment-status' defaultValue="Payment Status" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'epayments-id' defaultValue="ePayments ID #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label>{{ i18n 'payment-date' defaultValue="Payment Date" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'clearing' defaultValue="Clearing #" }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1">
                <label>{{ i18n 'view' defaultValue="View" }}</label>
            </div>


    <!-- panel-heading -->
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'so' defaultValue="SO #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ salesOrderNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'invoice' defaultValue="Invoice #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ invoiceNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'invoice-date' defaultValue="Invoice Date" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ moment invoiceDate format="MMM/DD/YYYY" }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'nf' defaultValue="NF #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ nf }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'payment-status' defaultValue="Payment Status" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ paymentStatus }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'epayments-id' defaultValue="ePayments ID #" }}:</span>
                <p>Teste</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'payment-date' defaultValue="Payment Date" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ moment paymentDate format="MMM/DD/YYYY" }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'clearing' defaultValue="Clearing #" }}:</span>
                <p>{{ clearingDocumentNumber }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-5 p-right-xs pl-md-3 p-left-xs p-bottom-md">
                <span class="visible-xs visible-sm content-desc">{{ i18n 'view' defaultValue="View" }}:</span> 
                <i class="material-icons" color="red">picture_as_pdf</i>
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```